# Java programming utility to create graph and chart in Linux

Tags: java, linux, charts

Can someone suggest me a Java utility or package to be used in java program running on Linux for creating graphs and charts which can be sent them as images to mail.

I looked up GNUPLOT utility which can be integrated with shell programming to achieve what I want, but we are not allowed to install this software. So I am left with java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/?

It has several diagram types.

Comment: Yes, but I have doubt whether it can be used without generating applets for drawing graphs as I will be using Linux server to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

[XChart](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart) would work. You can save a chart as a bitmap and then send it.

```
double[] xData = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };
double[] yData = new double[] { 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

// Create Chart
Chart chart = QuickChart.getChart("Sample Chart", "X", "Y", "y(x)", xData, yData);


// Save it
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./Sample_Chart", BitmapFormat.PNG);
```